# OpenID implementation in PHP

Tags: php, resources, openid

I am considering implementing OpenID on my website and I am having a hard time finding good resources for OpenID implementation in php. So far I have only found RPX but I don't want to depend on third party vendors. I want something similar to **SO** , can anyone point me in the right direction and can you also tell approximately how much time will it take to implement OpenID on my web site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about Simple OpenID via php classes.org?
http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3290.html

Comment: How much time would this take to implement?

Comment: Here's a link to a working example: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/15498.html

Comment: For estimating I would say 1hr for download install set up and 1hr to look over the code and get familiar with it. So 2hr + integration with your existing codebase.

Answer (score 3):

Zend Framework's [Zend_OpenId](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.openid.html) is a choice.

Comment: Hey can I use this with my custom framework since I am not using zend?

Comment: Yes, zf is usually very loosely coupled. Download the framework, set the include parh to your Zend folder and throw away most of the library except its OpenId file and folder (or keep the library since it's pretty useful :)